How to Implement User Inactivity Timeout with Okta and OIDC in a Spring Boot Application?
I have spring-boot app with few API endpoints exposed.
I’m integrating an OIDC sign-in flow with Okta in my Spring Boot single-page web app. I want to implement user session timeout for inactivity in my application, and also ensure that if a user logs out of Okta or loses access to the app via Okta, they are automatically logged out of my web app.

Inactivity session timeout: Users should be logged out automatically
if they are inactive for a certain period.
Session synchronization with Okta: If users log out of Okta or lose access to the
application in Okta, they should also be logged out of my web app.
Backchannel logout: It seems that OIDC backchannel logout could be
the solution for synchronizing the Okta session with my app’s
session. Does Okta support OIDC backchannel logout, and how can I
implement this in my Spring Boot app?

